# Train neural network with unlimited training data

Tags: deep-learning, neural-network, infinite

Does fitting a neural network with generated, and thus infinite training samples work?

Will the batch size still matter? Should training samples be repeated over some batches or is it ok to use every sample only once?

Does the term "epoch" makes any sense, if there is no complete dataset to iterate over?

Does validation makes any sense, if every sample from the training dataset already is  a new one? If not, will training loss behave like validation loss would?

Comment: The immediate obvious question is how do you know your input constitutes an "infinite" set of samples and, if you do know that, why do you need to train a network to identify them?

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever Infinite samples can be generated. Just one example: Draw randomly sized and scaled rectangles. We can do as many as we want then... The network can then learn to predict their size and orientation.

Answer (score 2):

> Does fitting a neural network with generated, and thus infinite training samples work?

Yes, it is completely fine, in fact it will likely be a much better setup than the one you are used to.

> Will the batch size still matter?

Yes, batch size controls noise in the gradient estimation, the bigger the batch, smaller the error.

> Should training samples be repeated over some batches or is it ok to use every sample only once?

If you can avoid repeating them, and just keep generating, you will be in a cleaner math setup, in practise it likely won't matter much.

> Does the term "epoch" makes any sense, if there is no complete dataset to iterate over?

The term "epoch" is one of the big mistakes that we made as a community, it really is meaningless even when dataset is finite. Avoiding it completely will simplify your life, just think in terms of gradient updates/samples consumed and forget the epochs.

> Does validation makes any sense, if every sample from the training dataset already is a new one? If not, will training loss behave like validation loss would?

It does still make sense just as an additional verification you are making progress, just remember to make sure you do not "generate" your validation set during training. That being said, it is much less important than in other cases, as long as your test scenario is also going to be generated in the same way. For example this is a reason why many RL papers (especially from Atari times) would not have validation sets - since training and test "environments" were exactly the same.